# Как при создании объекта параллельно создавать второй объект со схожими параметрами?

Tags: javascript, классы

Вопрос, мне необходимо что бы при создании объекта параллельно создавался второй объект со схожими параметрами, например общий текст, как можно этого добиться?
Например: есть новость, она создается при помощи класса, там есть картинка, заголовок, текст.
Так же существует кнопка, подробнее.
Мне необходимо что бы вместе с этой новостью создавалось модальное окно, которое при нажатии на кнопку подробнее открывалось, и там грубо говоря такая же информация, только больше текста.
Мне не нужно расписывать код, мне необходимо понять с помощью каких действий я могу этого добиться, код я напишу сам.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал не создавать второй объект, а тот же использовать... Можно сократить текст в первом варианте, а в модалке показать полностью...

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо, попробую так сделать, потом опишусь:)

Comment: Ответ от пользователя Air помог в решении проблемы.
Спасибо)